# How Can we create multiple instances of Ignite?

Tags: multithreading, ignite

How Can we create multiple instances of Ignite when multiple threads are trying to access same Ignite instance.

*Ignite ignite = Ignition.start("conf/example-ignite-config.xml");*

Here I have started/created one Ignite instance. But using same xml I have to create multiple instances of same without other thread to wait for it to get free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this, I created a *ClientGroup*, from one Ignite started in Client mode, i.e.(***Cluster group of nodes started in client mode.***) 
and when I need a Ignite node (grid) in client mode I just called a **ignite()** method of *ClientGroup* which gets instance of grid.

Answer (score 4):

`Ignite` instances are thread safe. You should call `Ignition.start` once and share it between all threads.

Alternatively, once Ignite has been started, you can obtain `Ignite` instance with `Ignition.ignite()` methods.

Comment: Hello I have created a Ignite instance as a Server, by _ Ignition.start _